# Connect a node to a hub with selenium grid 4

Tags: selenium-grid

I'm trying to connect 2 vm machines with each other (running both on win10).
I've downloaded java JDK 15 and

> selenium-server-4.0.0-alpha-6.jar

I'm running my hub, copying the TCP URL I get there (tcp://hub:4442/3) to my second machine.

But after running the node command I'm getting this message:

> Starting registration process for node ID X

and everything hangs...
I've tried testing if there is a connection using `Test-NetConnection` and it seems that there is communication between them

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK found the solution.
It seems that in alpha 6, if you don't have a browser web driver installed it won't work